# Show $A^*A$ is nonnegative operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

exercises from my lecturer too. I haven't found any idea.

Let $A$ be an arbitrary linear operator acting in unitary space $\mathbb{C}^n$ , and let $A^*$ be its adjoint. Prove that $A^*A$ is nonnegative operator. Prove that $A^*A$ is positive operator if $A$ is nonsingular.

Correct me if the statement in the problem seems wrong. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compute the inner product:

$\langle x \mid A^\ast A x\rangle = \langle Ax \mid Ax \rangle \geqslant 0$

and if $A$ is nonsingular, $Ax \neq 0$ for $x \neq 0$.